# Different display of blank values for two identical Excel charts

Tags: excel

I have two charts in my Excel file with the same series and the same options for displaying blank values, but the views of charts are different. Is there a way to make the left chart the same as the right chart?[image]

Excel file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AYP2FAH7pisI16WO-RaPX8gHXN6cpsQs/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do 2 things:

- Add Moving Average Trendline
  [image]
- Change the Trendline to solid
  [image]

Comment: I need the left chart to be the same as the right chart, not vice versa. I found the reason, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason was the hidden option "Show #N/A as an empty cell"  in my version of Excel (2016).

Excel 2016

[image]

Newer Excel version

[image]

This option was different for the two charts.
I used the following VBA code to change it in my version of Excel:
`ActiveChart.DisplayValueNotAvailableAsBlank = True`